# how to add primary key column with auto increment in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, auto-increment

i have one existing table in that i need to add primary column with auto increment(1,1). how to write query for to insert one primary key column with identity(1,1). getting error -

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY".

```
table ALTER TABLE OLTMS_0B8DF2
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

i tried like this

```
ALTER TABLE OLTMS_0B8DF2
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID) int IDENTITY(1,1);
```

getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use inline constraint syntax

```
ALTER TABLE OLTMS_0B8DF2
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE OLTMS_0B8DF2
   ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
       CONSTRAINT PK_OLTMS_0B8DF2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

You first have to create a new column and then you can define this column as the PK.